# Breaking bash script execution if passed file is of wrong extension

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, terminal

I have a small bash file that I used to compress PDFs and undertake some other file manipulations. I would like to break execution of this bash script if the passed file name does not have **`.pdf`** or **`.PDF`** extension.

#### Current approach:

```
# Take file name
fle_nme=$1

# Check if passed PDF file
# -ne - not equal
if ["${fle_nme: -4}" -ne ".pdf"] ||  ["${fle_nme: -4}" -ne ".PDF"]; then
        echo "Incorrect file."
        exit
fi
```

#### Current output

The script fails but without the desired message:

```
[me@onthebox bashStuff ERR]$ compressPDF ~/bashFun/failWithThisExtension.bad
compressPDF.sh: line 16: [.bad: command not found
compressPDF.sh: line 16: [.bad: command not found
```

### Desired results

- Execution of the script should finish
- Message *Incorrect file* should be printed to console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the if-conditional in `bash`, put spaces around `[`, `]` and always remember to quote your variables and remember `-ne` is for integer comparisons and *not* for string comparison.

```
fle_nme="$1"
if [ "${fle_nme: -4}" != ".pdf" ] ||  [ "${fle_nme: -4}" != ".PDF" ]; then
```

(or) you have a relatively recent version of `bash` you can set the `nocasematch` option available which will work for both `.pdf` and `.PDF`

```
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ "${fle_nme: -4}" != ".pdf" ]]; then
..

shopt -u nocasematch
```

Also worth adding that, the shell option you are setting needs to be disabled soon after the comparison is done. If not the option will be propagated to the rest of the script which might affect your other string comparisons.

---

As a side note, the best way to extract the extension from the filename would be to use parameter expansion syntax like below, this way you need not worry about the number of characters comprising of the file extension

```
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ "${fle_nme##*.}" != "pdf" ]]; then
```

Comment: I copied verbatim the first *`if`* line from the first solution but I was getting the same error. Second solution works.

Comment: @Konrad: Yup, re-used your own syntax for `-ne` which is meant for integer comparison, added now `!=` for string comparison

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct syntax.  It should be:

```
if [ "${fle_nme: -4}" != ".pdf" -a "${fle_nme: -4}" != ".PDF" ]; then
```

As Inian said, you need spaces.  Also, `-ne` is for numeric comparisons.  Finally, use `-a` for the **and** inside the brackets.

Inian's second option is best, **if** you also want to allow `.Pdf` and `.pDf` and all other such capitalation.